# Show images in specific grid layout: ejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, ejs

```
  <div class="row">
      <% for(var i=0; i < sImages.length; i++) { %>
      <img src="http://12.18.11.52:8980/public/uploads/<%=sImages[i]%>" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre"
        style="display: block;float: left;margin-right: 5px;">
      <% } %>
  </div>
```

this is what I have in my ejs template. I am generating pdf from this template and I want images resized by 33.33% and grid layouts like 3 images in the first row and 2 images in a 2nd row.
there will be no more than 5 images.
I have tried certain CSS tricks but didn't work

Comment: what are you getting right now? I think `margin-right: 5px;` breaks layout

Comment: In column i am getting

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions to achieve this layout, Here two simple ways like below:

```
<div class="row">
  <% for(var i=0; i < sImages.length; i++) { %>
  <img src="http://12.18.11.52:8980/public/uploads/<%=sImages[i]%>" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre"
    style="display: block;float: left;margin-right: 5px;width: calc(33.3333% - 5px);">
  <% } %>
</div>
```

**or**

```
<div class="row">
  <% for(var i=0; i < sImages.length; i++) { %>
  <img src="http://12.18.11.52:8980/public/uploads/<%=sImages[i]%>" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre"
    style="display: block;float: left;margin-right: 2%;width: 31.3333%;">
  <% } %>
</div>
```